# why does this status bar output garbled chinese like characters?

Tags: c++, statusbar, win32gui

my code to make the status bar is here:

```
int statwidths[] = {300, -1};
HWND hStatus;

hStatus = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_STATUS);
SendMessage(hStatus, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);

hStatus = CreateWindowEx(0, STATUSCLASSNAME, NULL,
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBARS_SIZEGRIP, 20, 20, 20, 5,
hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_STATUS, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETPARTS, sizeof(statwidths)/sizeof(int), (LPARAM)statwidths);

//SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Loading things...");
SetWindowText(hStatus, (LPCWSTR)"sdgsdfgd");
```

either of the bottom ways to set the status bars text just gives garbled Chinese like characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the following line

```
SetWindowText(hStatus, (LPCWSTR)"sdgsdfgd");
```

It should be

```
SetWindowTextW(hStatus, L"sdgsdfgd");
```

Also all of this depends on whether the windows is UNICODE or ANSI.

Comment: how do i fix the 
//SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Loading things...");
line? thats the one i need, but its a different type of string so the L"string" doesnt work.

Comment: i found it, its (LPARAM)L"Loading things..."

Comment: `SB_SETTEXT` expects a `TCHAR*`, not a `char*` or a `wchar_t*`, so use the `TEXT()` macro instead: `SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) TEXT("Loading things..."));` unless you know for a fact that `hStatus` is a Unicode window and that the app has been compiled with UNICODE enable (so `SB_SETTEXT` maps to `SB_SETTEXTW`).